# Enterprise Library Edit Orange Item doesn't show in vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7, enterprise-library

I've installed Enterprise Library 5.0 and update 0.1 both each time. I've installed nuget on my VS2012 too.

After injecting EntLib DataAccess to Refrences in VS through the Manage Nuget Packages panel online, I've added the needed assemblies.

The problem is when I add a new ".config" file, it doesn't show the orange `Edit configuration File` item when I right click on it!

I've watched the pluralsight tutorial movie of EntLib, and I did all things like that, I have EntLib configuration panel in my Windows/All programs but I can't have it through the right click panel in Visual Studio 2012.

I run as Administrator for sure.

EntLib.xsd also doesn't show in xmlschemas panel.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 does Not compatible with Win7(ultimate) .

So when you install "Enterprise Library.msi" it couldn't comunicat with VS and the EntLib orange item dosen't show on ".config" files.

To solve the problem use VS2012 new update.4 through one of this links

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36020
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305